# Adding and removing options for a choice field in New or Edit form

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2013

I am creating a screen that needs to remove and add some values to a choice field based on if certain fields have been provided.  My form requires certain fields to be provided during the Edit (not during the New).  So upon entering the screen, I remove some choice options from the Status field, in particular the value "Proposed".  Once the user changes other fields, I look to see if all applicable fields are now populated, I would like to re-add the "Proposed" option back as an choice.  This is needed below, near the end of the code.  The line is: (does not work though).

```
            $("select[title='Status'] option").add(ProposedOption);
```

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   //don't exectute any jsom until sp.js file has loaded.          
   SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', ChkUser);
});
function ChkUser()
{
        //var admingroup = "DMSDataManagement Owners";
        //console.log('selected='+'Admingroup='+admingroup);    
        //Lozzi.Fields.disableWithAllowance("Status",[admingroup]);
        //Lozzi.Fields.disable("Status");
        Lozzi.Fields.hide("ApprovedBy");
        Lozzi.Fields.hide("DateApproved");
        Lozzi.Fields.hide("PreviousStatus");

        var selectedValue = ($("h3:contains('Status')").closest('tr').find('select').val());
        //alert('Selected='+selectedValue);
        ProcessStatusValues(selectedValue);

        //on change of dropdown of Is this Critical we will call this
        $("h3:contains('DataDomain')").closest('tr').find('select').change(function () {
            //CheckMandatory(selectedValue);
            ProcessStatusValues(selectedValue);
        });
}
function ProcessStatusValues(selectedValue) {
        var ProposedFound = false;
        var ProposedOption;

        $("select[title='Status'] option").each(function(){
            if (selectedValue == 'In Process'){
               //console.log('value='+$(this).text());
           if(($(this).text() == 'Approved') || ($(this).text() == 'Obsolete'))
               {
               $(this).remove();
           }
               else if ($(this).text() == 'Proposed')
               {
                    console.log('found Proposed');
                   //ProposedFound = true;
                   if ($("h3:contains('DataDomain')").closest('tr').find('select').val() == '0')
                   {
                       ProposedOption = $(this);
                   $(this).remove();
                   } 
               } 
            }
            if (selectedValue == 'Proposed'){
            if(($(this).text() == 'Approved') || ($(this).text() == 'Obsolete'))
                {
               $(this).remove();
                       ProposedFound = true;
        }
            }
    })
       if (($("h3:contains('DataDomain')").closest('tr').find('select').val() != '0') && (ProposedFound == false)) {
            console.log('need to add Proposed');
            $("select[title='Status'] option").add(ProposedOption);
       }
}
</script>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add Proposed option to the select dropdown list like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$( document ).ready(function() {
 $('select[title="Status"]').append(`<option value="Proposed">Proposed</option>`); 

});

</script>
```

Reference:

[Add and Remove Options in Select using jQuery](https://paulund.co.uk/add-and-remove-options-in-select-using-jquery)